# surface of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$ below the plane $z=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

If $$\vec{F}=-y\vec{i}+x\vec{j}+xyz\vec{k}$$
Let $S$ be the part of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$ below the plane $z=4$ and oriented positively. Find $$\int\int_{S}curl(F).\vec{dS}$$

I have found the outward unit normal to the sphere giving:
$$\vec{n}=\frac{x\vec{i}+y\vec{j}+z\vec{k}}{5}$$

$$curl(F)=xz\vec{i}-yz\vec{j}+2\vec{k}$$

Now using parametric form of the sphere we have:
$x=5\cos u\cos v$, $y=5\sin u\cos v$, $z=5\sin v$

we have $|\vec{n}|=25\cos v$

so $$\int\int_{S}curl(F).\vec{dS}=\int\int_{D(u,v)}z(x^2-y^2+2)|\vec{n}|dudv$$

so
$$\int\int_{S}curl(F).\vec{dS}=\int_{u=0}^{2\pi}\int_{v=0}^{\pi}125\sin v\cos v(25\cos^2 v\cos 2u+2)dudv=250\pi$$

But ans is $-18\pi$  where i went wrong

Comment: Isn't $\vec{n}$ a unit vector?

Comment: Moreover, it seems to me the expressions are not appropriate to the intervals: e.g. if $z=5\sin v$ then the interval $ [0,\pi)$ is not the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Stokes' theorem:
$$\iint_{S}\operatorname{curl}{F}\cdot \vec{dS}=\oint_{C}F\cdot\vec{dr}$$
where $C$ is the boundary curve of the surface, given by the parametrization $\vec{r}(t)=(3\cos t,3 \sin t,4)$ (check that this is indeed the boundary) oriented clockwise, $t\in[0,2\pi].$

Then the integral boils down to computing 
$$\oint_{C}F\cdot\vec{dr}=-\int_{0}^{2\pi}F(\vec r(t))\cdot\vec{r}'(t)dt$$

Comment: yes i know that, but i want to get this problem done without using stoke's theorem